# addthis api? Is it possible to bookmark another URL?

Tags: bookmarks, addthis

At the moment, I try to include addthis social-bookmarks to my site.
My problem is, that I have to bookmark another link than the url on my site.
Instead of www.example.com, I have to bookmark www.example.com?media=my-media-file.

From the beginning:
A User comes to my site. On my site are several movies. He can click on a movie thumbnail and watch the movie without reloading the site (javascript). Now he can click on my social bookmark icon to share this movie.
Now the addthis framework thinks that the User want's to share www.example.com (cause this is whats in my url). But I want the user to share www.example.com?media=foo-bar .

Opening www.example.com?media=foo-bar for the correct movie is still working, but no social bookmaring.

I hope you understand my problem and can help me. I searched without success in the addthis api.

So, can u help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found it:

```
$('.addthis_button').attr('addthis:url',shareURL);
$('.addthis_button').attr('addthis:title',shareTitle);
$('.addthis_button').attr('addthis:description',shareTitle);
```